# How to use .load() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some javascript on my main page.  Later on, I load more content on user action through javascript using:

```
$("#div1").load(url+' #container');
```

My problem: I would like the javascript on the main page to apply to what is loaded now into div1.  However, this doesn't happen because (I believe) only the contents in #container from 'url' are taken and therefore the javascript doesn't apply to these contents.

How do I fix this?

An example is at http://agile-thicket-6078.herokuapp.com/readers/highlight/1# after you click on the highlighted 'assembled' on the left pane and then click 'Like' on the right pane.

Comment: Delegated event handlers !

Comment: @adeneo I'm not sure what you mean.  Can you provide more detail please?

Comment: @sharataka Did you try searching for it?

Comment: In case you forgot how to Google things: https://www.google.com/search?q=Delegated+event+handlers+&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t

Comment: In the example you have given, ´.load´ is a method of jQuery, not javascript, so you should refer to their documentation: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Not quite following your question? Do you have actions (such as `click`, `focus`, etc) whose actions aren't being called once you append new content? What **javascript** do you want to apply to what is loaded in ***div1***?

Comment: what the hell is #container?? hashtags have no meaning in http requests

Comment: @DavidFregoli The hash tag is not for the HTTP request. It's for fetching a page fragment. It is detailed clearly [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments) in the ***jQuery API Docs***...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the code you want to execute after loading contents to that **div** to a function:

```
function doSomething() {
    //
}
```

and do:

```
$("#div1").load(url, function () {
    doSomething();
});
```

Note that you don't need to bind event handlers bounded with `.on("SELECTOR")` again as **JQuery** do this automatically for dynamically added elements.

Answer (score -1):

** to apply to what is loaded now into div1 **

in main page write event like that

```
 $(document).on('click', '.liking', function (e) {
    //your function here
 });

 -- insteadof
  $('.liking').click(function (e) { });
```